# How to make it execute the functions after introducing the desired value?

Tags: python

Im new to python programming. I have this code which shoul execute the functions when introducing the desired value from a list, but after indtroducing the value nothing happens.

```
print("Problem 1.1")
print("Problem 1.2")
print("Problem 1.3")

sel=input("Introduce the number fo the problem you want to print:")
if sel == 1.1: 
 def mile_kilometri(): 
  print("Introduce miles")
  mile=input("mile=")
  km=int(mile)/float(0.6214)
  print("Miles in km:",km)
  mile_kilometri()
elif sel == 1.2: 
 def seconde_totale():
    print("Introduceti parametrii (hours,minutes,seconds)")
    o=input("Introduce the parameter hours:")
    m=input("Introduce the parameter minutes:")
    s=input("Introduce the parameter seconds:")
    sec1=int(o)*int(3600)
    sec2=int(m)*int(60)
    sect=int(sec1)+int(sec2)+int(s)
    print("The total number of seconds:",sect)
 seconde_totale()
elif sel == 1.3:
 def suprafata_dreptunghi():
  lat=input("Introduce first size of a square:")
  h=input("Introduce second size of a square:")
  aria=float(lat)*float(h)
  p=float(lat)+float(h)
  print("Area=",aria)
  print("Perimeter=",p)
 suprafata_dreptunghi()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input return a string. So in your condition you must have a string. Put the number in quotes like this :
`if sel == '1.1':`;
`if sel == '1.2':`;
`if sel == '1.3':`.

Comment: Thank you it really helped me out.